# Will GCP create a default VPC if not defined in Terraform when deploying a VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to the world of GCP and cloud computing in general.
I have a question regarding Terraform and GCP: if I don't define a VPC resource in my main.tf, will GCP create a default VPC to host my VM instance?

Thank you in advance for your response and have a great day.

My question might sound a bit peculiar, but while attempting to deploy an infrastructure using Terraform, I mistakenly named my network resources and noticed that a 'Default' VPC was created alongside the network I actually intended to deploy.
Hence, my query is whether GCP automatically provisions a default VPC when deploying without specifying a VPC resource or by making an error in declaring our resource?

Comment: No, nothing is automatic when you use infra as code.

Comment: Alright, thanks Guillaume for getting back to me.